# How do I access angular's $scope.{{formName}}.$dirty boolean with TypeScript?

Tags: angularjs, validation, typescript, angularjs-scope

I have a form with a name attribute, and I'm trying to use angular's `$scope` variable to access the form, and its `$dirty` boolean.

The problem is I'm using TypeScript, and if I set the type for a `$scope` variable to one of the interfaces `ng.IScope` or `ng.IFormController` from DefinitelyTyped's typings file, I can't type in something like

`$scope.myFormINeedToAccess.$dirty`

because everything is strongly typed, and if I do I get the error,

`Property 'myFormINeedToAccess' does not exist on type 'IScope'.`

or

`Property 'myFormINeedToAccess' does not exist on type 'IFormController'.`

Because I was introduced to AngularJS, and TS at the same time, I've not written any angular in javascript, but from what I think I understand the `$scope` variable (if variable is the right word for it) is accessible globally. So anywhere you want in any level of encapsulation you can just drop

`$scope.(tons of options/stuff in the current view).(a bunch of additional options)`

But I'm feeling very restricted by only being able to say

`$scope.(15ish options defined by ng.IScope or ng.IFormController)`

What can I do to use `$scope: ng.IScope` or `$scope: ng.IFormController` in such a way that I can successfully access the `$dirty` boolean via the statement,

`$scope.myFormINeedToAccess.$dirty`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Don't use `$scope` with Typescript - use `controller as` syntax.
2) Create a public variable of type `ng.IFormController` in your controller.
3) Set the `name` of your form to the variable created in #2.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as vm">
    <form name="vm.myForm">
        // form elements here
    </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
export class MyController() {
    public myForm: ng.IFormController;

    public someFunction(): void {
        if(this.myForm.$dirty) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

I've obviously left out quite a bit of the plumbing code, but this should give you the general gist.

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much! This totally worked! I've been at this for at least an hour banging my head against a wall, thanks so much! Why is it matching those names up, and using the controllerAs prefix in the name attr on the form tag makes those things sync up? Is that explained somewhere in some angular documentation?

Comment: Glad it helped! Angular uses the `name` attribute when binding to forms and form elements. This one had me baffled for quite some time, too, when I was starting out: if you need to access the individual form elements you'll have to create an interface because Typescript doesn't know anything about the form elements themselves.